# How can I detect if a value exists in specific array?

Tags: php, arrays

This is my array `animals`:

```
array(5) {
  [0]=>
  array(3) {
    ["number"]=>
    string(3) "123"
    ["cat"]=>
    string(4) "fred"
    ["dog"]=>
    string(3) "ted"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(3) {
    ["number"]=>
    string(3) "456"
    ["cat"]=>
    string(4) "todd"
    ["dog"]=>
    string(4) "jane"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(3) {
    ["number"]=>
    string(3) "789"
    ["cat"]=>
    string(3) "sam"
    ["dog"]=>
    string(3) "bob"
  }
  [3]=>
  array(1) {
    ["city"]=>
    string(7) "atlanta"
  }
  [4]=>
  array(1) {
    ["farm"]=>
    string(7) "johnson"
  }
}
```

I want to detect the following:

For each array that contains `number` I need to find out if `cat` and `dog` exist.

This is my try:

```
  foreach($animals as $row) {
       if (array_key_exists('number',$row)){                
          if(empty($row['dog'])){
             echo "dog missing";
          }
          if(empty($row['cat'])){
             echo "cat missing";
          }
       }
    }
```

So if I for example delete in my file `fred`, `ted` and `jane` my result is:

```
cat is missing
dog is missing
dog is missing
```

But I need to know more specific which cat or dog is missing. So the result I wish to have is:

```
cat is missing in number 123
dog is missing in number 123
dog is missing in number 456
```

My problem is that I do not know how to get the connection from the animal to the number.

Comment: Take a look at phps `array-walk()` function: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php

Comment: `echo "dog is missing in number ".$row['number'];`

Comment: You might want to use `array_key_exists()` or `isSet()` instead of the `empty()` because of false positives (`empty(0)` returns TRUE)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't you just add it to the echo? Like:

```
foreach($animals as $row) {
       if (array_key_exists('number',$row)){                
          if(empty($row['dog'])){
             echo "dog missing in number ".$row["number"];
          }
          if(empty($row['cat'])){
             echo "cat missing in number ".$row["number"];
          }
       }
    }
```

Comment: oh yes, this is true.. I was thinking to complicated :D

Comment: I was two mins faster :)